# Correct way to call a C DLL method from C#

Tags: c#, .net, c, dll

I'm trying to execute some methods (in this particular case, rdOnAllDone) from a third party DLL, written in C, and looking trough the headers files, I found this:

```
#ifndef TDECLSDONE
#ifdef STDCALL
#define     CCON        __stdcall
#else
#define     CCON        __cdecl
#endif
#define TDECLSDONE
#endif
#define     DLLIMP      __declspec (dllimport)
DLLIMP int CCON rdOnAllDone (void(CCON *)(int));
```

After goggling for a way to call this method, I made this:

```
[DllImport("sb6lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int rdOnAllDone(Delegate d);
public delegate void rdOnAllDoneCallbackDelegate();

private static void rdOnAllDoneCallback()
{
    Console.WriteLine("rdOnAllDoneCallback invoked");
}
```

The method was called correctly except that I couldn't get the int parameter. So I tried adding the input parameter int like this

```
[DllImport("sb6lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int rdOnAllDone(Delegate d);
public delegate void rdOnAllDoneCallbackDelegate(int number);

private static void rdOnAllDoneCallback(int number)
{
    Console.WriteLine("rdOnAllDoneCallback invoked " + number);
}
```

But now delegate is called twice and and it crashes the program with the following error " vshosts32.exe has stopped working"

What's the correct way to call this DLL method?

EDIT: Forgot to add the Main method:

```
public static void Main()
{
    rdOnAllDoneCallbackDelegate del3 = new rdOnAllDoneCallbackDelegate(rdOnAllDoneCallback);
rdOnAllDone(del3);

    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three things you need to do to make this work right:

- you need to tell the pinvoke marshaller about the *actual* delegate type, using Delegate isn't good enough.  That will create the wrong thunk that won't properly marshal the argument.  Which is what you saw happening.
- you need to tell the marshaller about the calling convention if it isn't __stdcall with the [UnmanagedFunctionPointer] attribute.  Getting this wrong imbalances the stack with good odds for a hard crash.
- you need to store a reference to the delegate object so that the garbage collector won't collect it.  It cannot see references held by native code.  Getting this wrong makes the native code fail with a hard crash after the next garbage collection.

So this ought to work better, tweak as necessary:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void rdOnAllDoneCallbackDelegate(int parameter);

[DllImport("sb6lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int rdOnAllDone(rdOnAllDoneCallbackDelegate d);

class Foo {
    private static rdOnAllDoneCallbackDelegate callback;   // Keeps it referenced

    public static void SetupCallback() {
       callback = new rdOnAllDoneCallbackDelegate(rdOnAllDoneCallback);
       rdOnAllDone(callback);
    }

    private static void rdOnAllDoneCallback(int parameter) {
       Console.WriteLine("rdOnAllDoneCallback invoked, parameter={0}", parameter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your delegates signature has to match that of the native callback, also it has to have the `UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute` set appropriately.

In your case like so:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void rdOnAllDoneCallbackDelegate(int parameter);

[DllImport("sb6lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int rdOnAllDone(rdOnAllDoneCallbackDelegate callback);
```

Usage:

```
{
    rdOnAllDone(rdOnAllDoneCallback);
}

private static void rdOnAllDoneCallback(int parameter)
{
    Console.WriteLine("rdOnAllDoneCallback invoked, parameter={0}", parameter);
}
```

Comment: Tried that right now and the delegate is still called twice and and it crashes the program with the same error " vshosts32.exe has stopped working"

Comment: You're right, I have tried it and experienced the same. After a bit of googling I found a working solution though and updated the post. :)