# C# GetFunctionPointerForDelegate cdecl instead of stdcall

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, function-pointers

I'm trying to work with a (C) third party library that has a callback mechanism that lacks any possible way of identifying the calling context. My main project is in C#, and my wrapper is a C++/CLI project to call the C library APIs.

To work around this problem, I'm attempting to use Marshal::GetFUnctionPointerForDelegate. Here is my C# code:

```
void Init(Handler Callback)
{
    // Create a wrapper lambda in case Callback is a non-static method.
    instance.CreateBuffers((x, y) => Callback(x, y));
}
```

Then, in the C++/CLI code:

```
void CreateBuffers(Handler^ Callback)
{
    pinCallback = GCHandle::Alloc(Callback);

    void (*callback)(int, int) = (void (__stdcall *)(int, int))Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(Callback).ToPointer(),
    // Use 'callback' in third party library...
}
```

The problem with all this is that according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367eeye0.aspx, the function pointer from Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate is an stdcall function, but my C callback is cdecl. How can I get a cdecl compatible function here?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart that would defeat the purpose of all of this, because I wouldn't be able to identify the calling context in the stub. I'd have to make a global __stdcall function pointer to know what to call, and then I'm back where I started.

Comment: The library has a function to call which accepts a struct argument containing a set of function pointers for various callbacks.

Comment: I only need to set them once per instance of the library usage, but there are multiple library instances active simultaneously in the application.

Comment: @dsharlet You can do what Jonathon suggests with, for instance std::function.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart "stub that does nothing but call **that** function pointer" That is the problem, I would need one stub for each function pointer, and I don't know that set at compile time. I edited the previous answer to your question to clarify that while I only set the callback once per library instance, there are multiple instances of the library I need to distinguish between.

Comment: @dsharlet really, std::function and std::bind are designed for this very purpose. However, I think there's a simpler way ...

Comment: Sorry for the mess of comments - I will delete them, as they don't really serve much of a purpose now. Good thing David came in to clear this up.

Comment: Just stumbled across this blog post: [Marshaling Delegates as `__cdecl`](http://winterdom.com/2008/01/marshalingdelegatesas__cdecl)

Answer (score 7):

I think that the simpest way to achieve this is to declare your delegate type is C# with the UnmanagedFunctionPointer attribute to specify the calling convention.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate ...
```

Then make your C++/CLI code receive a plain native C++ function pointer. You can pass an instance of your delegate, and because the delegate has that attribute, the marshaller knows what to do.

This allows you to skip the GetFunctionPointerForDelegate step. In fact it would allow you to skip right over the C++/CLI layer, but I expect that you don't want to do that.

Make sure that your managed code retains a reference to the delegate for as long as the unmanaged code can see the function pointer. If you don't do so then the garbage collector may pull the rug from under you since it cannot see the reference held by the unmanaged code.

This topic has been covered here before, of course. Hans Passant has a detailed answer here that is worth reading: [Correct way to call a C DLL method from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657805/correct-way-to-call-a-c-dll-method-from-c-sharp)

Comment: Would this override the behavior mentioned for [`Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at4fb09f.aspx) that says "using the __stdcall calling convention" ?

Comment: @Jonathon You would no longer be calling GetFunctionPointerForDelegate. The C++ code would receive a ready made unmanaged function pointer.

Comment: First of all, I *must* use a C++/CLI wrapper for reasons totally independent of this callback issue. Now, in order to make use of what you are saying, I had to make a native function that simply accepts a function pointer, and returns it as a void *. I declared this as DllImport in my C# code, with a delegate parameter, which is marked with the UnmanagedFunctionPointer attribute as in your answer.

Then, I use that function to pass the void * to the C++/CLI code that calls into the library (casting it to a function pointer). The callback simply never gets called.

Comment: The callback simply never gets called? How do you mean?